# Optionmenu is not updating

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
desk = Tk()

def new():
    win = Tk()
    mode = ['Debit Card', 'Credit Card', 'Net Banking', 'Paytm']
    mode_val = StringVar()
    pay_mode = OptionMenu(win, mode_val, *mode)
    mode_val.set('select mode')
    pay_mode.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.5)
    win.mainloop()
btn = Button(text='Book', command=new).pack()
desk.mainloop()
```

Here OptionMenu is not returning the value and it's not showing the Set "text", but it not updating mode by clicking it.

Comment: It is because you have used two instances of  `Tk()`.  Change `Tk()` to `Toplevel()` inside `new()`.

Comment: Or `mode_val = StringVar(master=win)` should do the trick too, but its not recommended to have more than one `Tk()`